# Save shopping cart content UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsuserdefaults

I'm working on converting an online store into a mobile application.

But I'm stuck on the shopping cart.

Here is what I'm doing:
I parse a product ID from the server and hand this is over to other view controllers to continue to work with it (eg. get the product image).

At the end I want to hand the product ID to the server again to complete the order.

My problem though is that my product ID is not being saved. Therefore my user can't leave the shopping cart now and come back later.

I'm trying to safe the shopping cart to the NSUserDefaults using a NSMutableArray which is placed into a NSArray (because NSMutableArrays cant be safed into the user defaults). But my array is not being saved by the user defaults. Here is my code:

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    if (warenID == nil) {
        nil;
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Id: %@", warenID);
        waren = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:100];
        [waren addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", warenID]];
    }

    if (waren == nil) {
        NSUserDefaults *warenkorbSpeichern = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [warenkorbSpeichern objectForKey:@"WarenkorbSpeichern"];
        NSLog(@"Waren: %@", warenSpeichern);
    } else {
        nil;
    }

    warenSpeichern = [NSArray arrayWithArray:waren];

    UIBarButtonItem *item = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction target:self action:@selector(remove)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = item;

}

-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];

    NSUserDefaults *warenkorbSpeichern = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [warenkorbSpeichern setObject:warenSpeichern forKey:@"WarenkorbSpeichern"];
    [warenkorbSpeichern synchronize];
    NSLog(@"Gespeichert: %@", warenSpeichern);
}
```

I save the NSMutableArray into an NSArray which is then saved into the user defaults via viewDidDisappear (I use this so I don't have to saved it everywhere. Just when the user leaves the view controller. This way my user can edit his/her shopping cart as often as they want without me having to worry about is it being saved everywhere).

What am I doing wrong? I just don't get it...